# Multiconditional average of values of columns of a categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
DRUG READING1 READING2 READING3 TEMPERATURE
A     1          2        3       12
A     1          2        3       12
A     2          2        1       14
A     2          3        3       16
B     8          9        7       12 
B     8          8        8       14
B     8          9        9       14
B     9          8        7       16 
C     12         11       12      12
C     11         11       11      12
C     12         11       11      14 
C     12         11       11      14
C     11         12       12      14
C     11         12       11      16 
C     11         12       12      16 
D     20         21       21      12
```

Now I want to replace the values of a particular Drug 'C' with the average values of the readings belonging to the particular temperature for the final outcome to be something like this

```
DRUG READING1 READING2 READING3  TEMPERATURE
A     1          2        3           12
A     1          2        3           12
A     2          2        1           14
A     2          3        3           16
B     8          9        7           12 
B     8          8        8           14
B     8          9        9           14
B     9          8        7           16 
C     11.5       11       11.5        12
C     11.5       11       11.5        12
C     11.7       11.3     11.3        14 
C     11.7       11.3     11.3        14
C     11.7       11.3     11.3        14
C     11         12       11          16 
D     20         21       21          12
```

or other way to see this is:

```
DRUG READING1 READING2 READING3  TEMPERATURE
A     1          2        3           12
A     1          2        3           12
A     2          2        1           14
A     2          3        3           16
B     8          9        7           12 
B     8          8        8           14
B     8          9        9           14
B     9          8        7           16 
C     11.5       11       11.5        12
C     11.7       11.3     11.3        14 
C     11         12       11          16 
D     20         21       21          12
```

Comment: Have you already tried some code?

Comment: df.pivot_table(df, values='Reading 1', index='TEMPERATURE', aggfunc='mean') but I need the outcome for the different temperature ranges of drug C only

Answer (score 0):

This is `groupby().mean()`:

```
df.groupby(['DRUG', 'TEMPERATURE'], as_index=False).mean()
```

Output:

```
  DRUG  TEMPERATURE   READING1   READING2   READING3
0    A           12   1.000000   2.000000   3.000000
1    A           14   2.000000   2.000000   1.000000
2    A           16   2.000000   3.000000   3.000000
3    B           12   8.000000   9.000000   7.000000
4    B           14   8.000000   8.000000   8.000000
5    B           16   9.000000   8.000000   7.000000
6    C           12  11.500000  11.000000  11.500000
7    C           14  11.666667  11.333333  11.333333
8    C           16  11.000000  12.000000  11.500000
9    D           12  20.000000  21.000000  21.000000
```